# Ошибка сборки после обновления gradle plugin

Tags: android, gradle, build

[image: Ошибки при сборке]

**Build.gradle app**

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.company.denis.{здесь название приложения на латин}"
        minSdkVersion 19 // it was 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.+'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.microsoft.azure:azure-mobile-android:3.4.0@aar'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

}
```

**Build.gradle Project:**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    }

}
```

Находил уже обсуждения такого вопроса, но там проблема в том, что путь не на латинице, у меня же на латинице, плюс в настройках указан путь C:/Users/denis/.gradle

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.company.denis.{-appName-}"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="19"
        android:targetSdkVersion="26" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.company.denis.{appname}.activities.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.VERSION"
            android:value="26.1.0" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.authentication.RedirectUrlActivity"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.authentication.CustomTabsIntermediateActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.authentication.CustomTabsLoginActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:launchMode="singleTask" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.arch.lifecycle.VERSION"
            android:value="27.0.0-SNAPSHOT" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: оно ругается на манифест. на пермишны. показывайте манифест

Comment: Изменил, добавил манифест

Answer (score 2):

Вынесите пермишен на интернет из тега `application`

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19"
android:targetSdkVersion="26" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```